# How to disable the “Expect: 100 continue” header in WinRT's HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpwebrequest, windows-runtime

I'm developing an app that for legacy code reasons I can't upgrade for the new `HttpClient` so I'm using `HttpWebRequests`.

In .NET 4 we could deactivate the Expect header (on posts requests) using  [`ServicePoint.Expect100Continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue.aspx) property, but on WinRT it's not available.

How can this be accomplished on WinRT?

EDIT: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` is not available either.

Comment: You can't remove Expect from the request header collection?

Comment: No because it isn't there, the header is automatically added when I begin waiting for the response.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the ContinueTimeout (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.continuetimeout.aspx) property, lke setting -1 or 0 or MaxValue. This seems to be the only related property supported by the WinRT version... (no ContinueDelegate, no Expect, no SendChunked, no ServicePoint)

Comment: ContinueTimeout with 0, -1 or int.maxvalue doesn't help

Answer (score 64):

```
var c = new HttpClient();
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```

Comment: As I said I can't use httpclient

Comment: Sorry saw that after I posted. Unfortunately the code to modify the HttpWebRequest ExpectContinue property has been explicitly blocked. This is the only way to get rid of it.

Comment: Unable to find property ExpectContinue:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.headers.httprequestheadercollection.aspx  Am I reading a wrong document?

Answer (score 12):

Put this is your webconfig.

```xml
<system.net>
  <settings> 
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>  
  </settings> 
</system.net>
```

Also works!
I use this in my webapplication. But answer above is equally as good!

Comment: The question is specifically about WinRT, will that work there too?

Comment: I don't think that that is an option on Winrt since the ServicePointerManager doesn't exist XD.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only option you have it to override BeginGetRequestStream. HttpWebRequest has a private method MakeRequest and in it the Expect100Continue header is added to the request header collection.

Comment: How can I accomplish that? The HttpWebRequest class has an internal constructor...

Comment: I found a better solution. Did you try this:
HttpWebRequest webRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( "http://something" );
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

Comment: that option is not available on winrt XD